# I'm having trouble making my add method

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def __str__(self):
        return "This number is {}".format(self.number)
    def __add__(self, second):
        self.number = self.number + second.number
        return self
c1 = Test(1)
c2 = Test(2)
c2 = c1 + c2
print(c2)
print(c1)
```

Output:

```
This number is 3
This number is 3
```

my trouble is that it changes the c1 and c2, when I try to add them. How do I keep c1 the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a new object:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return "This number is {}".format(self.number)

    def __add__(self, second):
        return Test(self.number + second.number)
```

Note that when you rebind `c2` like this:

```
c2 = c1 + c2
```

its original value is lost. With your code, both `c1` and `c2` will point to the first `Test` object (`c1 + c2` returns `self` from `c1`'s `__add__`).

With my code, the original second object will be deleted and a new object will be bound to `c2`.

Comment: I thought it had to do with something like that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the fact that you modify self in your `__add__` method.  You're not supposed to do that (though you can, since Python considers all people involved to be "consenting adults"... and sometimes, it would be the correct solution.  Though I can't think of a scenario where it would be)

And `self` in your `__add__` method gets bound to c1, so you modify c1; and then you assign it to c2.

Try adding `print(c1 is c2)` at the end.  It will print `True`.

Pavel's `__add__` behaves as an `__add__` method is supposed to.